# can process and icon of iPhone app be hidden by code?

Tags: iphone, process, icons, hidden, jailbreak

after jailbroken my iPhone 3GS, i was always worried about the security since i stored most of my id/password on it. recently i had a little concern that maybe some apps i installed on my phone didnt have an icon and i couldnt see the process via sbsetting as well. so that means there're some apps on my phone that i can never get access to and i dont even know what they are doing.

and as a developer, im quite interested how can process and icon hidden be achieved by code. with these technologies, a good daemon can be made to serve iPhone users.
so my question is, am i thinking too much or process and icon hidden really exist in iPhone? if the answer is yes, how can i do this by code? any clues are welcome!

thx a lot!

cheers

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a daemon background process. You're probably not going to learn how to program a unix daemon process here. However there are a variety of ways to get a program to run in the background. Pick a Unix compatible programming language, find a good book on the subject, go to Starbucks, buy some coffee and enjoy.

Comment: sorry but maybe u misunderstood my question... what i wanna ask is that how can i hide the process info(i.e. users cant see it via sbsetting)and icon of my daemon by code?